# get the right result for inserting into the database - Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, forms, laravel

Im trying to store data in this table:

newspaper_id

article_id

comment (string)

This is how my HTML looks like:

```
<div class="newspaper-options">
    <input class="form-control" name="data[]" type="text">
    <input type="checkbox" class="article-option" name="article_id[]" value="3"> Active
</div>

<div class="newspaper-options">
    <input class="form-control" name="data[]" type="text">
    <input type="checkbox" class="article-option" name="article_id[]" value="1"> Active
</div>
```

This is the result im getting back when i only fill in the second newspaper options and check it:

```
"comment" => array:2 [▼

    0 => ""

    1 => "option 2"

  ]

  "article_id" => array:1 [▼

    0 => "1"

  ]
```

The problem im having is how can i group the input values so i can store it inside my table. The value of my checkbox is that of the article_id. and the text field is used to fill the comment inside the database.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: whats the purpose of `data[]` in text fields ?

Comment: well there are multiple input fields and i was trying to group the text field with the checkbox.

Comment: what did you get when you post your form ? Have you done print_r ? Please do `print_r($_POST)` and paste in the question and also what you require.

Comment: aren't they already grouped ?

Comment: yeah but i have no idea if this is the right way and how i can store this into the database :/

Comment: http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/requests
http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/database

Comment: I have updated the post you can clearly see there is no relationship between comment and article_id

Comment: please share your table structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The information that is missing to correctly put that info into the database is the mapping of the array position to the article_id.

E.g. put
    `<input name="article[]" type="hidden" value="...">`
in each `<div class="newspaper-options">`

Like so

```
<div class="newspaper-options">
    <input name="article[]" type="hidden" value="3">
    <input class="form-control" name="data[]" type="text">
    <input type="checkbox" class="article-option" name="article_id[]" value="3"> Active
</div>

<div class="newspaper-options">
    <input name="article[]" type="hidden" value="1">
    <input class="form-control" name="data[]" type="text">
    <input type="checkbox" class="article-option" name="article_id[]" value="1"> Active
</div>
```

Then in your Controller you can loop through Input::get('article'), check the active checkbox and add the comment.

E.g.

```
foreach(Input::get('article') as $pos => $article_id){
    if(in_array($article_id, Input::get('article_id')){
        add $article_id and Input::get('comment')[$pos] to DB
    }
}
```

---

Apart from that you should get a better name for your article_id field, like "active" and change "data" to "comment".

---

If you could add the input fields with keys in the first place you could handle them more easily. I guess it is possible to do

```
<input class="form-control" name="data[3]" type="text">
<input type="checkbox" class="article-option" name="article_id[3]" value="3"> Active
```